# Why am I still able to use support-v4 library without importing it on gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, support-v4

I am confused, in my gradle I have not imported support-v4, yet I seem to be able to use the library, is support-v4 included as dependency by default? See below? Also on my project folder, I can see the jars support v4 everytime I create a project and the individual modules?

project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ok.applicationtest_v4lib"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

-activity below is able to import support-v4 without needing to import support-v4 in gradle:

```
package com.example.ok.applicationtest_v4lib;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        //I am able to use below class yet I have not imported v4 library.
        ActivityCompat
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `appcompat-v7`, you have `appcompat-v4`.

Run `./gradlew app:dependencies` and you will see

```
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0 (*)
```

Comment: And `support:design` includes v7, so even that one isn't necessary

Comment: So, by that logic if i am including dependency support-design on my gradle I do not need either appcompat-v7 or appcompat-v4 right?

Comment: you shouldn't be "optimizing" that way.  If your code needs certain library set up proper dependency in your gradle. Does not matter if any other lib depends on the same library. Fulfilling your dependencies is NOT a task of that lib. One it may stop depend on that lib or prefer other version that makes you troubles. And you are doomed - this is easily avoided - just manage own dependencies

Comment: Is it safe to remove support-v4 and appcompat-v7 if I already have support-design? or there is a cyclic dependency between those?

Comment: even if does circular dependency. it is not a problem as gradle know how to deal with it. leave it.

Comment: All I am trying to do is remove support-v4 from my project and only including the indpendent modules from support-v4 such as support-compat, support-coreui, etc.  However, if support-design adds support-v4 automatically this doesn't seem possible.  I have removed support-v4 from gradle and appcompat-v7 and all the classes from support-v4 are still found in my project by just keeping support-design.

Comment: Doesn't proguard remove those unused stuff in your release apk?